# Is this string  ascending or descending?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help in checking that string is ascending or descending and I have problems with it.
so it's my "$a_n$"
$$
\sqrt {n+5} - \sqrt{n}
$$

and I need to use $a_{n+1} - a_n$ or $\frac {a_n+1}{a_n}$.

EDIT:
it would be something like that 
$$
\sqrt {n+6} - \sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}
$$
and what's next?

Comment: What do you mean? The former term is clearly greater than the latter.

Comment: Yes but it would be something like that 
$$
\sqrt {n+6} - \sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}
$$
and what's next?

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align*}
a_n &= \sqrt{n+5}-\sqrt{n} = \left(\sqrt{n+5}-\sqrt{n}\right)\frac{\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{\left(\sqrt{n+5}-\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{n+5 - n}{\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{5}{\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}} \\
\end{align*}

This is clearly a decreasing sequence. As $n$ increases, the denominator increases so the sequence as a whole decreases.

---

If you insist on using $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, use the same approach above to show that:

\begin{align*}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} &= \frac{\sqrt{n+6}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+5}-\sqrt{n}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+6}+\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{align*}

Now, notice that:

$$
n+1 \gt n \Rightarrow \sqrt{n+1} \gt \sqrt{n}
$$

And:
$$
n+6 \gt n+5 \Rightarrow \sqrt{n+6} \gt \sqrt{n+5}
$$

Add the inequalities side by side to get:

$$
\sqrt{n+6} + \sqrt{n+1} \gt \sqrt{n+5} + \sqrt{n}
$$

Divide both sides by $\sqrt{n+6} + \sqrt{n+1}$ to get:

$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\sqrt{n+5}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+6}+\sqrt{n+1}} < 1
$$

Comment: The OP needs to use $a_{n+1} - a_n$ or $\frac {a_n+1}{a_n}$.

Comment: @Gigili - Added a proof using $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

Comment: Great, Plus-one'd.

Answer (score 4):

How about calculus?

Differentiate the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x+5}-\sqrt{x}$. We get $f'(x) = \frac12(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x+5}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}})$. This is negative for all $x\ge 0$ because $\sqrt{x}$ is strictly increasing. Therefore our $f$ is strictly *decreasing*, so the sequence formed by taking its values at discrete $x$s is decreasing too.

Answer (score 3):

$(\sqrt {n+5} - \sqrt{n})\times(\sqrt {n+5} + \sqrt{n})={n+5} - {n} =5$ which is constant.

But $\sqrt {n+5} + \sqrt{n}$ is increasing with positive $n$ so $\sqrt {n+5} - \sqrt{n}$ is decreasing.

Comment: Much the same as Ayman Hourieh's answer, but perhaps easier to understand for some readers